# AngularJS Unit Test Directive with Input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I am using Angular v1.6 with Jasmine and I'm trying to unit test a working directive in our angular application by entering an input value but I cannot get the directive to fire properly.

Directive

```
.directive('percentage', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

                function fromUser(value) {
                    return value / 100;
                }

                function toUser(value) {
                    return Math.round(value * 100);
                }
                ngModel.$parsers.push(fromUser);
                ngModel.$formatters.push(toUser);
            }
        };
    })
```

Unit Test

```
describe('percentageDirective', function() {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

      // Inject $rootScope and $compile
      var scope, element;
      beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        // Set up the scope with test data
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        scope.value = 0;

        // Create an element
        element = angular.element('<input type="number" percentage ng-model="value"></input>');

        // Compile that element with your scope
        element = $compile(element)(scope);

        // Run the digest cycle to compile the element
        $rootScope.$digest();

        // Find the input control: 
        var dirElementInput = element.find('input');

        // Set some text
        angular.element(dirElementInput).val('25').triggerHandler('input');

        scope.$apply();
      }));

      it("should display the decimal value", function() {
        expect(scope.value).toEqual('0.25');
      });
});
```

The scope value never changes and remains at 0. Can someone help on how to trigger the input change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have an issue with `element.find('input')`, `find` searches at the children of the given element, it won't return as a result the element itself. Therefore, all your operations are made on an empty angular element wrapper.

If you will try to `console.log(dirElementInput.length)` you will see that this wrapper is empty.

You can change that to `var dirElementInput = element[0];` and the test will pass.

Working example:
https://embed.plnkr.co/DVUoMAUcDXcMl6tp521D/